# Why I'm getting this error when I use a variable with SCSS?

Tags: css, angular, sass

I'm using Angular and *scss*, but when I try to import a variable, I get this error:

`SassError: Undefined variable.  border: $color-red 2px solid;`

But I have defined that variable in my file:

[image]

And I'm using it in this way:

[image]

[image]

I have tried setting the path like this: `@import url("./global/_colors.scss");`, with an underscore, but it doesn't work.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@import "./global/_colors.scss";
```